# PostgreSQL: How to read parallel explain analyze (rows doesn't match single thread)

Tags: sql, postgresql, parallel-processing, explain

I am joining two tables, main (ui_cdc_s5_misto_cas_zdroj_aggregace) indexed table and dependent table (ui_cdc_s5_misto_cas_zdroj_aggregace_zdrobneni) via id, dependent table has 9 131 407 rows.

```
select *
from ui_cdc_s5_misto_cas_zdroj_aggregace a 
left join ui_cdc_s5_misto_cas_zdroj_aggregace_zdrobneni az on a.id = az.id
where 
  a.bod_vykonu_kod = 5433355900 
  and a.kod_kzam = 83121 
  and a.datum between '2017-01-01'::date and '2018-03-01'::date
```

If run non-parallel it works as I would expect it applies index scan on main table and will get 4042 rows, on dependent table it applies seq scan and take all the 9 131 407 rows and does hash join.

[image]

Explain analyze non-parallel: https://explain.depesz.com/s/5xjm

Then if I allow parallel processing the number of rows for dependent table doesn't match if I sum all actual rows I am at 8 602 360. Also the rows for main table doesn't match as well.
NOTE: this numbers seems to vary with each execution.

```
->  Parallel Seq Scan on reports.ui_cdc_s5_misto_cas_zdroj_aggregace_zdrobneni az  (cost=0.00..87618.15 rows=2945615 width=24) (actual time=0.035..939.911 rows=3043802 loops=3)
      Output: az.id, az.zahranicni, az.pul_den, az.v_vytizeni
      Buffers: shared hit=58162
      Worker 0: actual time=0.027..1149.377 rows=2835236 loops=1
        Buffers: shared hit=18059
      Worker 1: actual time=0.050..1191.181 rows=2723322 loops=1
       Buffers: shared hit=17346
```

Explain analyze parallel: https://explain.depesz.com/s/1HHN

Why does the number mismatch, is it because it really doesn't read the whole table (seems unlikely to me) or there is some other logic in it?

> PostgreSQL 11.5 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5
>   20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36), 64-bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I admit that this is confusing.

The relevant line in the parallel plan is the first one:

```
rows=3043802 loops=3
```

The row count is an average, so it is a third of the actual rows (compare with the non-parallel plan).

This is so that you arrive at the correct number by doing the customary operation of multipying tha data with the loop count.

The other row counts contain the information how many rows the worker processes contributed to the grand total. Because that is information about just one process, (`loops=1`), the number is not divided.

So in this case we can deduce that the leader process has contributed more rows to the result than the worker processes.

Comment: Then I guess other numbers like actual time are also average, because 939.911 is less than any of the two worker processes, meaning that leading process ended sooner than them making that average time?

Comment: I would say so, yes.